# Import data from excel file to database with AJAX and Laravel 8

Tags: ajax, laravel

If someone can help me import the data from an excel file to a Database using AJAX. Using Submit if I get it, I need to do the same with AJAX. Thank you for your support!

When using AJAX it shows the following error:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thvOs.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uxgo8.png) are the browser error logs.

ROUTE

```
Route::post('mantenimiento/validar',[ImportController::class,'import']);
```

CONTROLLER

```
class ImportController extends Controller {
    
    public function import(Request $request) {
        $file = $request->file('select_file');

        $import = new VfichaImport;
        $import->import($file);

        if ($import->failures()->isNotEmpty()) {
            // return back()->withFailures($import->failures());
        }

        return 'Hola import';
    }
}
```

FILE IMPORT

```
public function model(array $row) 
{
    ++$this->numRows;
    return new Vficha([
        'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
        'apellido' => $row['apellido'],
        'edad' => (integer) $row['edad']
    ]);
}

public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'nombre' => ['required'],
        'apellido' => ['required'],
        'edad' => ['required']
    ];
}

public function getRowCount(): int 
{
    return $this->numRows;
}
```

VIEW

```
<!-- MODAL  -->
<div class="modal fade modal-slide-in-right" data-backdrop="static" aria-hidden="true" 
role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="confirmModalCarga">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-Label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">x</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">UPLOAD FILE</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <!-- FORM -->
            
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=" 
  {{url('mantenimiento/validar')}}" id="formcarga">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                <table class="table">
                <tr>                                                
                    <td width="40%" style-align="right"><label>FILE:</label></td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="fichaid" id="fichaid" value="">
                    <td width="30">
                        <input type="file" id="select_file" name="select_file" 
accept=".xlsx,.xls" require /><br>
                        <button type="submit" id="bCargar" name="bCargar" class="btn btn- 
primary">Cargar</button>
                    </td>                   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td width="40%" style-align="right"></td>
                <td width="30"><strong><span class="text-muted" style="color:red;" 
id="stexto"></span></strong></td>
                <td width="30%" style-align="left"></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
            </form>             
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" id="btnValidar" name="btnValidar" class="btn btn- 
 success">VALIDATE FILE</button>
            <button type="submit" id="btnCargar" name="btnCargar" class="btn btn- 
 primary">SAVE FILE</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cerrar</button>
            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END MODAL  -->
```

AJAX

```
$('#btnValidar').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/mantenimiento/validar',
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#formcarga').serialize(),
    }).done(function(res) {
        alert(res);
    });
})
```

Comment: It may be an issue relative to your `import` method code. Try to change `$import = new VfichaImport;` to `$import = new VfichaImport();` (You were not using curly braces in the constructor call)

Comment: Thanks for replying @Luca Pizzini, I made the change and it keeps showing the error

Comment: Are you trying to navigate directly to `http://localhost:8000/mantenimiento/validar`? Because that won't work, you don't have a GET route defined for that url.